# UI:repeat does not increment the id of table row

Tags: jsf-2, uirepeat

In JSF 2 (SUN RI ) UI:repeat does not increment the id of table row when new rows are added. It does display all rows on browser. However, view source reveals only one row.

```
<ui:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{b.items}" var="itemBean" varStatus="status1">
<table>
 <ui:repeat id="repeat2" value="#{a.locations}" varStatus="status2" var="loc">
  <tr>
   <td> <h:inputText    id="date" size="10" maxlength="10"</td>
  </tr>
 </ui:repeat>
</table>
</ui:repeat>
```

id - > `myForm:repeat1:0:repeat2:0:date`

I am expecting it to be `myForm:repeat1:0:repeat2:1:date` for a new row added. But am 
getting same row id `myForm:repeat1:0:repeat2:0:date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is recognizeable as one of the older Mojarra bugs. Upgrade to the latest [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) which is currently 2.0.9 / 2.1.9.

By the way, the name "Sun RI" does not exist anymore since version 1.2_08 at December 2007. It has become "Mojarra". The name "Sun RI" was never been used on JSF 2.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your quick reply and for clarification. I knew you are the one who is going to answer my question:). Thanks again.